# Warning message: ggrepel: 1 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps

Tags: r, pca

The code:

```
res <- PCA(decathlon, quanti.sup = 11:12, quali.sup = 13, ind.sup = 1:5)
```

gave me this message

> Warning message: ggrepel: 1 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps).
> Consider increasing max.overlaps

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. If no further messages appeared, nothing went wrong.

The PCA function produces a plot with the `ggplot2` package and uses the `ggrepel` package to add nice labels for data points. The special thing about ggrepel is that it uses an iterative algorithm to place the labels in a way such that they do not overlap with each other or with the data points ([more about ggrepel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html)).

However, sometimes the data points are too crowded together and the algorithm finds no solution to place all labels. This is what your message means by "1 unlabeled data points". If it is no problem for you to have one unlabeled point in the plot, you can just ignore the message.

Comment: what if that unlabeled data point is necessary to be part of the plot? I have experienced this issue and I don't know what to do. thank you for your help!

Comment: There are several [options](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html#options) that affect the iterative algorithm's behavior. In your case, I would play around with these and see if they make a difference. Specifically, try: lower `box.padding`, higher `max.time` and/or higher `max.iter`, and different ratios between `force` and `force_pull`. You may also want to [allow more overlapping labels](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html#always-show-all-labels-even-when-they-have-too-many-overlaps). The entire page in these links should be very useful, by the way.

Comment: Thank you @benimwolfspelz, the issue has been solved with setting `max.overlaps=Inf`. thanks a lot for reaching out to me!